# How to generate self-closing tag <tag/> for empty element in XML using JAXB

Tags: java, xml, java-8, jaxb, marshalling

A sample code with `jaxb-api` `2.3.1` and Java 8 using `StringWriter` for `jaxbMarshaller`:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "currencyCode",
    "discountValue",
    "setPrice"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "countryData")
public class CountryData {
    protected String currencyCode;
    protected String discountValue = "";
    protected String setPrice = "";

    // setters and setters
}
```

When I marshal the entity to a XML string with:

```
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
jaxbMarshaller.marshal(countryDataObject, sw);
sw.toString();
```

How to get expected result for empty values?

```
<currencyCode>GBP</currencyCode>
<discountValue/>
<setPrice/>
```

Actual output:

```
<currencyCode>GBP</currencyCode>
<discountValue></discountValue>
<setPrice></setPrice>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't initialized the variables. use the `nillable` attribute and set it value to `true`

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = { "currencyCode", "discountValue", "setPrice" })
@XmlRootElement(name = "countryData")
public class CountryData {
    @XmlElement(nillable=true)
    protected String currencyCode;
    @XmlElement(nillable=true)
    protected String discountValue;
    @XmlElement(nillable=true)
    protected String setPrice;
    // getters and setters
}
```

output

```
<currencyCode>GBP</currencyCode>
<discountValue xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
<setPrice xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
```

Comment: Thanks Lakshan. However, I need to have the output: <setPrice/> without other attributes. So how to remove "xmlns:xsi" and "xsi:nil"?

Comment: @rongmei this is not a Industry standard solution. but it fulfill your requirement. https://stackoverflow.com/a/47283792/8700934

Comment: yes. That given linked solution would fulfill my requirement as a workaround. I still wonder any Lib can provide choice of self-closing tag. Seems many are looking for this option as well.

Comment: @rongmei please refer this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/17366633/8700934

Comment: great, thanks, the referred link does help me. I got <setPrice/> self-closing tag now. Similar solution with cleaner doc: http://www.nocker.com.au/index.php/2019/05/16/jaxb-marshal-to-xml-json-printing-all-null-fields/

Answer (score 0):

Although the strings are empty they still contain non-null data and the end tag is generated. Remove the default values of the strings or set them as `null` (a default instance field value):

```
protected String discountValue;
protected String setPrice;
```

The tags become closed:

```
<discountValue/>
<setPrice/>
```

Comment: Thanks Nickolas. Remove default values + don't set value, "setPrice" tag is removed from generated XML. If I set value null (in an object instance), "setPrice" tag also disappears.

Comment: Nikolas, sorry, my previous comment was not clearly read. The suggestion removed empty tag completely. I don't get the output of <setPrice/>. Till now, I still don't have working solution.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace them:

```
.replaceAll("<\w+></\\1>","<$1/>")
```